# T-SQL stuff column into another column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two columns (`A, B`)  like this....

```
A           B
12_18_19    20
```

I want a 3rd column (C) added within same `SELECT` statement like this...

```
C
12_18_20_19
```

in other words, my column `A` is delimited by "_", so the second last index of column `A` should be column `B`.

If possible I would do do all this within same `SELECT` statement like this...

```
A         B    C
12_18_19  20   12_18_20_19
```

Comment: What if `B` is empty? What if `A` is empty? What if both `A` and `B` are empty?

Comment: *Why* is column `A` storing delimited values in the first place? That's usually a bad sign.

Comment: 12_18_19 stores the breadcrumb menu for website, otherwise i have to run recursive queries to get all sub categories to create the menu's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
    A, B, 
    C = SUBSTRING(A, 1, LEN(A) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(A))) + 
        '_' + B + 
        SUBSTRING(A, LEN(A) + 1 - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(A)), 999)
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
```

It's a bit involved, mostly also because there is no `LASTCHARINDEX()` function in T-SQL.

The first expression parses the `A` column up to the last `_` separator characters and takes everything before that. Then it appends a `_` and column `B`, and then grabs everything *after* that last `_` separator from `A` and appends that.

And as Andriy M rightfully mentioned in his comment : if `A` or `B` are `NULL`, then the whole result is NULL, too. If the columns are empty strings, or if `A` doesn't contain any `_` characters, you'll might get errors (since the parsing will fail) or [unexpected, messy results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4604).

Answer (score 1):

Edited to handle more situations after Andriy's analysis.

Although @Marc_s' answer works, this is a slightly better solution

```
SELECT A,B, stuff(a+'  ', len(A)+2- charindex('_',reverse(A)+'_') 
,0, case when A='' then B ELSE B+'_' end) C 
FROM 
(SELECT '12_18_19' A, '20' B) t
```

Replace last line with your table

Comment: Both @marc_s's solution and yours seem to work correctly only when `A` has an `_` and `B` is not empty. However, when the first condition is not met, I think @marc_s's solution [fails more gracefully](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4625) in comparison.

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks for your input. I altered the script to handle those situations. Let me know if you find more exceptions.

Comment: Nice. I was thinking about changing `B+'_'` to `COALESCE(NULLIF(B,'')+'_','')` to get rid of an extra `_` when `B` is empty and `A` isn't, but that might not necessarily be what the OP wanted, judging by the fact that they've accepted @marc_s's solution (which has this the extra `_` issue too). As for other possible edge cases, can't think of any at the moment. Those I mentioned first seemed to me the only ones that needed attention (apart from the NULLs, of course). So, nice job handling them!